# WYSIWYG Submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, wysiwyg

I have never faced this problem until now.
I have a normal fully functional submit form with a textarea which has an WYSIWYG HTML editor. (Nicedit, but i tried different ones already).

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

And when i try to submit, nothing happens... When i remove the script to run the Nicedit and try to submit, the form does his normal work!

I'm using Chrome.
Already tried in a local virtual server and on my real server.

Comment: How are you trying to submit? Submit button? Hitting enter? niceEdit shouldn't be overriding any of that.

Comment: I'm using Submit type button...
Is there any problem?
How can i change it? Is that recent? Because i never had problems before!

Comment: I can't see the page but niceEdit would not be rejecting your form submit capability.

Comment: WI found the problem.. I wouldn't call it a problem, but i found the a solution :D

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('area').saveContent();" />

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem already!

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('area').saveContent();" />
```

Needed to add an onclick tag to my submit button to save the content inside the textarea. Odd but it's working :)

Thanks for all the support.

Comment: Once again i found my problem...
I have a Facebook script running at the same time, so i bet it was causing some trouble!